# Unit test for Spring DTO that has a Collection for a Field in Hibernate/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Hibernate and the JPA with Spring Boot.

I have a DTO which would collect information from a Contact, which, is envisioned to come from a form from the client side which would could potentially have multiple phones sent:

```
public class ContactDTO {

   private BigInteger userId;
   private String contactName;
   private Map<String, BigInteger> phones;

   // getters and setters
}
```

I'm imagining the data will be sent in a JSON object in this format:

`{phones:[{"mobile":"2325552932"}, {"landline":"2235553329"}, ...]`

And I have a controller with a POST method designed to handle that:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/newContact")
  public String createNewContact(@ModelAttribute ContactDTO newContact) {
    if (newContact.getPhones() !=null) {
      // method that persists phone data
    }
   // .. use a CRUDRepository object to persist the data to MySQL DB
    return "savedContact";
  }
```

I guess my questions are twofold:

1. will my controller be able to automatically map the JSON object in that format?
2. How would I test that?

I'm using the Spring Boot test, and they look something like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AdditiveControllerShould {

  @Autowired
  private AdditiveController additiveController;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Test
  public void saveAnEntryWhenPOSTOnlyUserIdAndContactName() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/newContact")
            .param("userId", "12345")
            .param("contactName", "John Smith"))
           // how to run test for the Map<String, BigInteger> ???
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("savedContact")));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Controller** :

```
 @PostMapping(value= "/newContact")
  public String createNewContact(@RequestBody ContactDTO newContact) {
    if (newContact.getPhones() !=null) {
      // method that persists phone data
    }
   // .. use a CRUDRepository object to persist the data to MySQL DB
    return "savedContact";
  }
```

**Test Class**:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class AdditiveControllerShould {

     @Autowired
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

     private static final ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

     @Test
      public void saveAnEntryWhenPOSTOnlyUserIdAndContactName() throws Exception {
         Map<String,String> phones=new HashMap<>();
         phones.put("phone1", "12345");
         Map<String,Object> input=new HashMap<>();
         input.put("userId", "123456");
         input.put("contactName", "TEST");
         input.put("phones", phones);
         mockMvc.perform(post("/newContact")
               .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(input))
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))           
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

      }

}
```

output:

```
CONTACT ContactDTO [userId=123456, contactName=TEST, phones={phone1=12345}]
```

Comment: I think that's close but it's giving me an error: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [app.models.relationentities.Contact] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class app.models.relationentities.Contact, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}`

Comment: I thought perhaps it was an issue with a name of the variable, so I changed `input.put("contactName", "TEST");` to `input.put("name", "TEST");` but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: It looks like problem with the validation. ensure you are getting the contactDTO instance and from there you can take it on. I was able to get the instance inside the controller.

Comment: Got it, if I took these out: `input.put("userId", "123456");
         input.put("contactName", "TEST");`
And instead put `.param("name", "TEST")` after the `mockMvc.perform(post("/newContact")` , the test seemed to pass.